# How to display GtkTreeView with dummy data in Vala

Tags: gtk3, vala

I'm trying to display a GtkTreeView in a GtkApplication Window with some dummy data using Vala.

The problem is that the window appears to be empty, but after a closer look using GtkInspector I can see that the GtkTreeView is there but looks to be empty even thought the model is properly set and it has the appropriate data.

The code I have so far is:

main_window.vala:

```
using GLib;
using Gtk;

namespace MediaOrganizer
{
    public class MainWindow: Gtk.ApplicationWindow
    {
        /* public constructor(s)/destructor*/
        public MainWindow(string title)
        {
            Object(
                border_width    : 0,
                window_position : WindowPosition.CENTER
            );
            header_ = new Gtk.HeaderBar();
            fileModel_ = new FilesystemModel();
            fileView_ = new Gtk.TreeView();
            mainLayout_ = new Gtk.Box(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 0);

            this.set_default_size(800, 480);

            header_.set_title(title);
            header_.set_show_close_button(true);
            this.set_titlebar(header_);

            fileView_.set_model(fileModel_);

            this.size_allocate.connect(on_size_changed);

            mainLayout_.add(fileView_);
            add(mainLayout_);
        }

        void on_size_changed(Gtk.Allocation size)
        {
        }

        /* private variables */
        private Box mainLayout_;
        private Gtk.HeaderBar header_;
        private FilesystemModel fileModel_;
        private Gtk.TreeView fileView_;
    }
}
```

filesystem_model.vala:

```
using GLib;
using Gtk;

namespace MediaOrganizer
{
    public class FilesystemModel: Gtk.TreeStore
    {
        public FilesystemModel()
        {
            GLib.Type columnTypes[2] = {
                typeof(int),
                typeof(string)
            };
            set_column_types(columnTypes);

            Gtk.TreeIter it;

            append(out it, null);
            set_value(it, 0, 0);
            set_value(it, 1, "aaaa");

            append(out it, null);
            set_value(it, 0, 1);
            set_value(it, 1, "bbbb");

            append(out it, null);
            set_value(it, 0, 2);
            set_value(it, 1, "cccc");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a TreeViewColumn for each column of your store : http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.TreeView

Comment: I knew it must have been something simple I overlooked. Thanks alot!